# MySQL - how to select rows with a unique name?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, select

I have the following structure in the table:

```
id | name     | descr
1  | BMW      | asafsf saf
2  | Audi     | asafsf saf
3  | Audi     | asafsf saf
4  | Porsche  | asafsf saf
5  | Mercedes | asafsf saf
6  | Mercedes | asafsf saf
7  | Audi     | asafsf saf
```

I would like to grab all the companies that have only one record in the table, so in this case, the output would be like:

```
1  | BMW      | asafsf saf
4  | Porsche  | asafsf saf
```

How could this be done (I've tried grouping, but that will also scrap other companies with multiple rows in the table)?

PS: I am using Ruby On Rails, so maybe there is a method in ActiveRecord for that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, descr FROM mytable AS tbl1
JOIN (
    SELECT name from mytable
    WHERE COUNT(*) = 1
    GROUP BY name
) as tbl2
ON tbl1.name = tbl2.name
```

Comment: The Problem is, that just with distinct or group by etc the information of the  second column is lost. Thatswhy a join is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GROUP BY and just keep the results having one row using the HAVING clause: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

```
   SELECT id, name, descr
     FROM tablename
 GROUP BY name
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `DISTINCT` keyword. (see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, id, descr FROM tablename
```

Output:

```
id | name     | descr
1  | BMW      | asafsf saf
2  | Audi     | asafsf saf
4  | Porsche  | asafsf saf
5  | Mercedes | asafsf saf
```

Old query:

```
SELECT name, id, descr FROM tablename
```

Old output:

```
id | name     | descr
1  | BMW      | asafsf saf
2  | Audi     | asafsf saf
3  | Audi     | asafsf saf
4  | Porsche  | asafsf saf
5  | Mercedes | asafsf saf
6  | Mercedes | asafsf saf
7  | Audi     | asafsf saf
```

Comment: Thats simply wrong. The DISTINCT keyword will give you a distinctive list of every name in the table. So the output would be: BMW, Audi,Porsche,Mercedes. The descr column would be lost in the result set.

Comment: Thanks. I have forgotten to add the other rows (just copied output from question) and the `name` and `id` column. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActiveRecord

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct

```
Car.select(:name)
# => Might return two records with the same name

Car.select(:name).distinct
# => Returns 1 record per distinct name

Car.select(:name).distinct.distinct(false)
# => You can also remove the uniqueness
```